# Music Before Eric Idle's "Storytime/Children's Stories" in Monty Python Season 1 Episode 3?

Tags: soundtrack, monty-python

There's some springy orchestral music that plays as an introduction to Eric Idle's "Children's Stories" sketch in Season 1 Episode 3.  This is the sketch where Rumple Tweezer lives by Dingly Dell and uses contraceptives, etc.

What is the name of that music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tune is a piece of production music called Holiday Playtime, written by Cedric King-Palmer.

http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0658150/